# confusing operation in java

Tags: java, netbeans

[image]

I tried to execute this piece of java code in NetBeans but as I debug it step by step , whenever I bring the cursor of the mouse inside it to check the value of 'a' variable , It will be incremented strangely and the output shows the wrong answer. 
What is the problem?

Comment: Using netbeans 11.2 and openjdk 11 debug shows a value of 10. Which is correct. Update netbeans maybe. If that is not the case, update jdk.

Comment: I mean whenever I debug this I will get different answer in output . the output is not constant . Once I debug it and I got 42 in output. How is it possible?

Comment: I'm not sure how you can get 42 in the output print of the console. If you are referring to the debug pop-up it is not meant to be reliable, but in netbeans-version 11.2 I found the pop-up 'a= 10'.

Answer (score 0):

The post increment (a++) evaluates the value and after that it will be incremented. The pre increment (++a) increments the value and after that it gets evaluated. So, if you use a=1 and you go a++ + +aa you will have evaluated on that line a=3 and on the next line it will be a=4.

Comment: No , You did not get the picture . I mean whenever I debug this I will get different answer in output . the output is not constant . Once I debug it and I got 42 in output. How is it possible?

Comment: Is that the only code you have? Do you have a warning on 'a', or why is it in yellow?

Comment: Yes , that is the only code and no warning . The color is Yellow because I drag it to check the value